# New windshield wipers seem ineffective

Tags: opel, windshield-wipers, windshield, astra

My car, a 2004 Opel Astra, has new windshield wipers. Whenever I go to use them (since it's the start of winter right now) they wipe some water off, but it's never a "clean" wipe (like a .. residue? on the windshield) and it makes a god-awful screeching noise.

It wipes the entire area that I expect it to wipe, but I have extremely sensitive hearing and moderate tinnitus, which makes this scenario almost impossible for me to drive with.

Is it possible that the windshield got damaged since it was standing for a while (due to broken gearbox)? If so, what steps could I take to fix this? I have Googled for windshield polishing, but honestly I have no idea how to interpret the results, or if that's even the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thank you! I have loads more questions, but I'll start here :p

Comment: What have you tried to do to clean the windscreen? If the windshield is still clear, it is most likely not damaged in any way. It more than likely just needs to be completely cleaned. Using some IPA or acetone might do the job.

Comment: I will do, thanks. I'm completely clueless on this topic, and my local shops usually gouge me when I ask for help :)

Comment: If you lift the wiper arms, do they move freely under the tension of the spring, or have they become stiff due to corrosion where they pivot up?

Comment: Are the new blade a good quality brand?

Comment: If you have no idea of the work, but you say they "gouge" you - how do you know? Perhaps understanding the knowledge and skills they have before passing an opinion may be a good idea.

Comment: @handyhowie they don't move on the windshield, but they stay down

Comment: @solar-mike because where I live, sales workers take as much advantage as they can, especially in hardware or mechanic shops according to my cousin (their family are all BMW mechanics). I don't know much about cars but I know a bit about the shops :)

Comment: @gear4 so all the customers are gullible...